# Extracting a specific value from txt file using python

Tags: python

I have a set of data I'm working with that appears in a text file like: 
Sensor Data

[image]

I want to extract the RSSI data from each line of code.

```
with open ('datasensorsmall.txt') as f:
for line in f:
    TS, Drop, RX, TX, RSSI, CRCData, light, temp, humidity = line.split("   ")
    print(RSSI)
```

However, it only prints the first RSSI value and then I get an error value that says:

```
"ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 9, got 1)".
```

How do I solve` this?

Comment: if you want to split by white space just use line.split() .No need to add "  "

Comment: I imagine that the data is tab separated and not space separated, which is why that's not working. `line.split()` or `line.split('\t')` (if you don't want to split on all whitespace).

Comment: @Mufeed I get an error that says "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 9, got 0)". It prints out the first line's RSSI value, which leads me to think there's something going wrong in the iteration of the code.

Comment: What do you get if you just print out line.split() without unpacking it into 9 variables?

Comment: yeah. Just check if you get list of 9 values when you print line.split()

Comment: @dashiell 
['TS:1530213030647', 'Drop:33', 'RX:64', 'TX:03377', 'RSSI:-32.50', 'CRCData:0c87018c0330', 'light:135', 'temp:39.60', 'humidity:816']
[]
['TS:1530213030659', 'Drop:0', 'RX:64', 'TX:03377', 'RSSI:-34.50', 'CRCData:0c87018c0330', 'light:135', 'temp:39.60', 'humidity:816']
['TS:1530213030671', 'Drop:0', 'RX:64', 'TX:03377', 'RSSI:-34.00', 'CRCData:0c87018c0330', 'light:135', 'temp:39.60', 'humidity:816']
['TS:1530213030682', 'Drop:0', 'RX:64', 'TX:03377', 'RSSI:-33.50', 'CRCData:0c87018c0330', 'light:135', 'temp:39.60', 'humidity:816']

Comment: It's pretty hard for us to test your code (or our modified versions of it) on your data because it's in a PNG file. Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). A small excerpt in text form would be much better, and for this question a few lines of hexdump would show us if the file is delimited by tabs, or if their are other non-printing characters in there.

Comment: got it. There is an empty list in between.

Comment: you have a blank line i guess

Comment: @user10012049 problem solved?

Comment: @Mufeed Yep, thanks!

Comment: I added little modification to your code so that it won't happen in future.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is there is a blank line in the text file. So to avoid such scenarios, you could use something like

```
with open ('datasensorsmall.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if not line.strip():   # this line will ignore blank line
            TS, Drop, RX, TX, RSSI, CRCData, light, temp, humidity = line.split()
             print(RSSI)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex for this

```
import re
with open ('datasensorsmall.txt') as f:
for line in f:
    rssi = re.findall('RSSI:(.*?)\s*C', line)
    print(rssi[0])
```

Comment: Thanks, I used this and it worked for my RSSI values, but I also want to collect my light values. What does .*?)\s*C mean in the code?

Comment: If it helped you kindly upvote it. Back to your question, `RSSI:(.*?)\s*C` it is a regex pattern which means after 'RSSI:' whatever(.*?) there is just capture that until one or more space(\s*) followed by character 'C'

Answer (score 0):

Not enough values to unpack means your split is not yielding enough strings to assign to all of those variables.

So throw in a conditional if length of split is 9, then do your assignment.

Or avoid multiple assignment because this isn’t well suited to it, and just iterate through your split, assigning to as many target variables as strings your split yields.